# visual studio x64 incompatibility

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2010

So I've been trying to install VS 2010 on windows 8. I know it works on windows 7, and I just recently upgraded to windows 8.

Since I'm a student, I downloaded my version of VS 2010 from the MSDNAA website, to which my school is subscribed to.

I can't install, nor even mount the .iso (which is strange...). Since I'm also developing for C++, and my instructor for my C++ course insists on using the g++ compiler, I've downloaded the Ubuntu ISO as well, and I also can't mount it.

In both cases, both the VS 2010 ISO and Ubuntu ISOs are corrupt. I don't think that this is the issue, as I can extract both ISOs fully with no errors. I just can't mount it.

After extraction, I clicked the setup.exe file that came out of the VS 2010 ISO, and I was presented with the following message:

```
The program or feature /*file path to iso*/ cannot start or run due to incompatibility 
with 64-bit versions of Windows. Please contact the software vendor to ask if a 
64-bit Windows compatible version is available.
```

Any ideas/solutions on what to do?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to set the compatibility mode for the VS2010 setup to Windows 7?

Comment: yup, tried that nothing happens. Same error pops up. Interestingly enough, if I do run as administrator on the setup file, windows says FILE NOT FOUND.

Comment: Do you use the inbox ISO mounting functionality? If yes, try other 3rd party tools like "Virtual Clone DRIVE"

Comment: I had no problem installing VS2010 on a 64-bit installation of Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VMWare Player, a free desktop virtualization client.  For Visual Studio:

- Click "Create a New Virtual Machine."
- Select "Installer disk image file (iso)" and browse to your Visual Studio ISO file.
- Click "Next."
- Under "Guest Operating System," click "Other"
- Under "Version," click "Other."
- Click "Next" until you see the "Ready to Create Virtual Machine" screen.
- Click "Finish."

And for Ubuntu:

- Click "Create a New Virtual Machine."
- Select "Installer disk image file (iso)" and browse to your Ubuntu ISO file.
- Fill out all fields until you see the "Ready to Create Virtual Machine" screen.
- Click "Finish," and Ubuntu should now boot up.
- Go through the graphical installer.
- Ubuntu should reboot and say "Installing VMWare Tools."  This will take a while, so relax and let it finish.
- Ubuntu is now installed in the Virtual Machine.